# Issue Validating URL in VBA Regex

Tags: regex, ms-access, url, vba

I have the following function to test if the string passed to it matches the regex pattern supplied. This seems to be working fine with other validator function I have created.

```
Private Function IsRegexMatch(ByRef sText As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Boolean
    IsRegexMatch = False

    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Pattern = sPattern

    Set Matches = regex.Execute(sText)
    If Matches.Count = 1 Then IsRegexMatch = True

End Function
```

Then I have the following function to validate URLs. I am aware that the actual W3C spec for URLs is much more complicated, but for the sake of my application I just need to check the following:

1. Uses HTTP or HTTPS
2. The domain/subdomain is valid
3. The URL is not pointing to the webroot (there must be some path attached)

   ```
   Public Function IsValidURL(ByRef sURL As String) As Boolean

       IsValidURL = False

       sPattern = "^" 'Beginning of string
       sPattern = sPattern & "https?:\/\/" 'Protocol is http or https
       sPattern = sPattern & "[\w\d][\w\d\-]*(\.[\w\d\-])*" 'Domain/Subdomain
       sPattern = sPattern & "\.[\w]+" 'gTLD
       sPattern = sPattern & "\/" 'we need to not be in the webroot
       sPattern = sPattern & ".+" 'Check that we have stuff that comes after the slash

       IsValidURL = IsRegexMatch(sURL, sPattern)

   End Function
   ```

For some reason I can't get past my second test case:

```
Private Sub Test_IsValidURL()

    Debug.Assert IsValidURL("http://www.google.com/something")
    Debug.Assert IsValidURL("https://www.google.com/something")
    Debug.Assert IsValidURL("https://collab.mycompany.net/sites/hereweare")

    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("http://www.google.com/")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("https://collaboration")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("ftp://collaboration")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("htps://collaboration")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\somemachine\somefolder")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\somemachine\somefolder")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\som.emachine\somefolder")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\some.machin.e\somefolder")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\some.machin.e\somefolder\folder2")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\somemachine\somefolder\")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\somemachine\somefolder\")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\som.emachine\somefolder\")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\some.machin.e\somefolder\")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\some.machin.e\somefolder\folder2\")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("\\4some.ma24chin.e124\somefolder\folder2\124")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("my_file")
    Debug.Assert Not IsValidURL("my_fi/le")

    Debug.Print "PASSED: IsValidURL"

End Sub
```

I feel like I must be making a stupid error somewhere in there, can somebody help me out?

Much appreciated :)

Comment: why is `"http://www.google.com/"` not a valid URL? You are asserting that it is not, when by your definition in the regex it is so it breaks there. Is that intentional? Either you need to reject URLs with a trailing / or you need to remove the Not ;)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey I corrected that issue by changing the "*" to a "+" on the last part of the pattern, but I'm still running into an issue with the second case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "Domain/Subdomain":

`(\.[\w\d\-])*` => `(\.[\w\d\-]+)*`

Just tested all your cases in SublimeText with this correction and they all validate/invalidate correctly.

Also, you don't need to escape `-` if it's the first or last character within the class.

Comment: Thank you! I should have caught that, but I guess I've been staring at this screen for too long.

Comment: Happens to us all. :)